# Internal server error on Data Management API (GET search)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Today we get internal server error on the search method.
Before today almost all was fine (except this method returns "Too many requests" very often).

We call Data Management API to get all versions with "rvt" extension

[GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/)

We get

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"1b2ec532-d1ec-4ed2-a174-02fb6a097195","status":"500","detail":"Internal Server Error"}]}
```

What is a root cause of this issue?
What we can use to filter versions without any error?

Comment: Could you share the `x-request-id` of the API call you received for the internal server error? If you haven't had one, please try to pass an extra request header `x-request-id` to each API call you made to `GET search`. The `x-request-id` could be any valid string, but would advise you to pass a meaningful string like `company name-guid`

Comment: Sure. Errors.id =  462face1-02c2-4517-9afe-79f125dc3c00. `X-Request-Id = 7ab4c940-dc30-4a39-846d-4ed84c4a2d3e`

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking with our engineering team. Will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: @EasonKang Any updates?

Comment: Works again! Hope for a long)

Comment: @EasonKang Again doesn't work. Getting Internal Server Error.

Comment: I replied to the support ticket you raised to the Forge help email.

Comment: Could you have a try? I cannot reproduce this issue on my side now. Feel free to get back if the problem comes

Comment: Yesterday after several hours from my comment time it started working again. Today it works. Will let you know if something changes.

Comment: Thank you for your good news. Yeah, feel free to let us know if the problem persists. We are monitoring it on our side as well.